# One httpClient for many method in one class

Tags: c#

I would like to use one httpclient to many method in class.
Below is the simplified code:

public class test{

private readonly HttpClient _httpClient;

```
public Test(){
_httpClient = new HttpClient();
}

public void method1(){
using (_httpClient){
//...
}
}

public void method2(){
using (_httpClient){
//...
}
}

public void method3(){
using (_httpClient){
//...
}
}
}
```

Then it calls the method data:

```
public async static void TestHttpClient()
        {
            Test test1 = new Test();
            test1.Method1();
            test1.Method2();
            test1.Method3();
        }
```

Method 1 is working. When calling the second one I get the message: "You cannot access a deleted object."

Thanks for helps.

Regards

Comment: Why do you want to reuse the same client? Is creating multiple clients a performance problem for you?

Comment: You shouldn't keep creating and disposing HttpClient - Look at this https://www.aspnetmonsters.com/2016/08/2016-08-27-httpclientwrong/

Comment: @RubbleFord That article is outdated given the introduction of `IHttpClientFactory`.

Comment: Your using statement is causing your error. I wouldn't use a static instance.

Comment: HttpClientFactory is the way to go these days. The HttpClient life cycle is very complicated; the factory manages all those details

Answer (score 3):

`using` calls the `Dispose()` method after the scope - which destroys the object - keep the instance of your `HttpClient` within the instance of your object

```
public class test : IDisposable
{
    private readonly HttpClient _httpClient;
    public test()
    {
        _httpClient = new HttpClient();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _httpClient.Dispose();
    }

    public void method1()
    {
        //...
    }
}
```

then you can dispose your object instead of the HttpClient

```
using(test myObject = new test()) 
{
    myObject.method1();
    myObject.method2();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want `Test` to create and reuse a disposable resource (e.g. `HttpClient`, then `Test` should implement `IDisposable` and should dispose of the resource in its `Dispose` method. That means that the class *using* `Test` should use a `using` block:

```
public async static void TestHttpClient()
{
    using (Test test1 = new Test())
    {   
        test1.Method1();
        test1.Method2();
        test1.Method3();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is to create a private variable and a get accessor

```cs
    private HttpClient _httpClient;
    
    private HttpClient MyClient 
    {
        get {
            if (_httpClient == null)
            {
                _httpClient = new HttpClient
                {
                    BaseAddress = new Uri($"https://your.url/")
                };
                //Other client logic goes here
            }                
            return _httpClient;
        }
    }
```

Then from your method, you just reference the accessor

```cs
public async Task method1()
{
    await MyClient.Post() //post logic here
   //...
}
```

You don't need to dispose HttpClient, MS recommends leaving the object in place, unless you know you need to forcibly close the connection.